# Updating uniqueidentifier column with same value for rows with matching column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a little help. I have this (simplified) table:

| ID | Title | Subtype | RelatedUniqueID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | My Title 1 | 1 | NULL |
| 2 | My Title 2 | 1 | NULL |
| 3 | My Title 3 | 2 | NULL |
| 4 | My Title 4 | 2 | NULL |
| 5 | My Title 5 | 2 | NULL |
| 6 | My Title 6 | 3 | NULL |

What I am trying to accomplish is generating the same uniqueidentifier for all rows having the same subtype.

So result would be this:

| ID | Title | Subtype | RelatedUniqueID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | My Title 1 | 1 | 439753d3-9103-4d0e-9dd0-569dc71fd6a3 |
| 2 | My Title 2 | 1 | 439753d3-9103-4d0e-9dd0-569dc71fd6a3 |
| 3 | My Title 3 | 2 | d0f08203-1197-4cc7-91bb-c4ca34d7cb0a |
| 4 | My Title 4 | 2 | d0f08203-1197-4cc7-91bb-c4ca34d7cb0a |
| 5 | My Title 5 | 2 | d0f08203-1197-4cc7-91bb-c4ca34d7cb0a |
| 6 | My Title 6 | 3 | 055838c6-a814-4bd1-a859-63d4544bb449 |

Requirements

- One query to update all rows at once
- The actual table has many more rows with hundreds of subtypes, so manually building a query for each subtype is not an option

Using SQL Server 2017

Thanks for any assist.

Comment: Is `Subtype` a foreign key to a `Subtype` lookup table?

Comment: No, just an integer.

Comment: @Dale-k I purposely left out what I had tried, to avoid steering people in a certain direction, and to see new unique ways of tackling this issue.

Comment: @Onthrax We need to see what you have tried - thats how this site works - not only does it help clarify the problem but it shows us you have actually had a go.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the single query solution.

Pre-requirement for this to work is that RelatedUniqueID must already contain random values. (e.g. set default field value to newid)

```
UPDATE TestTable SET ForeignUniqueID = TG.ForeignUniqueID FROM TestTable TG INNER JOIN TestTable ON TestTable.SubType = TG.SubType
```

**Update**
As Stu mentions in the comments, this solution might affect performance on large datasets. Please keep that in mind.

Comment: This would work as expected or am I missing something?

Comment: The "pre-requirement" would seem to be the separate step you want to be part of the same query. If performance is a concern, either answer below will be faster. This is effectively a cross join, looking at logical reads it is almost 100% more with the same sample data and will grow exponentially.

Comment: I had not considered performance factors. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: I haven't downvoted you? If it works in your particular case then that would appear ok.

Comment: Wasn't directed at you, but someone did. Can't see who, or I would have 'tagged' them.

Answer (score 1):

Because `newid()` is applied per-row, you have to generate the values *first*, so this has to involve the use of a temporary or permanent table to store the correlated ID>Subtype value.

So first you need to generate the GUID values per *Subtype* :

```
with subtypes as (
    select distinct subtype
    from t
)
select Subtype, NewId() RelatedId into #Id
from subtypes
```

And then you can use an *updatable CTE* to apply these to your base table:

```
with r as (
    select t.*, id.RelatedId
    from #id id
    join t on t.subtype=id.Subtype
)
update r
set relatedUniqueId=RelatedId
```

[See example DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e2f783f0f062e2eb78ca3cf549d35192)

Comment: Thank you, this is very usable, but I'm still looking for a single query solution. I might have come up with something. Doing tests now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an updatable CTE with a window function to get this data:

```sql
with r as (
    select t.*,
      RelatedId = first_value(newid()) over (partition by t.Subtype order by ID rows unbounded preceding)
    from t
)
update r
set relatedUniqueId = RelatedId;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=34f606bd04073adae2dadb2d26577081)

---

I warn though, that `newid()` is somewhat unpredictable in when it is calculated, so don't try messing about with a joined update (unless you pre-save the IDs like [@Stu has done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69115313/14868997)).

For example, see [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ce4c4bfdb513f71c2e542041fd77977a), the IDs were calculated differently for every row.

Comment: If it works reliably, that's a neat solution for newid() using a window function. I say *if* as the fiddle you created seems broken :)

Comment: Fixed now I think